# Delete File in Flutter For android 12 and 13

Tags: android, flutter

I am not able delete file in android 12 and android 13 device.

error:

> ════════ Exception caught by Flutter framework
> ═════════════════════════════════ The following FileSystemException
> was thrown: Deletion failed, path =
> 'storage/emulated/0/Download/VideoCompress/Audio/AUD10_3_2023_2526sample-5s.aac'
> (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: Please add your code also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.